# Website shows different letters when accessed from a different locality

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, character

A client reported that his Website is full of typos. When i went and checked this I did not see this, so he sent pictures.
I cannot publish all of the pictures for the sake of the client.

The client is currently on holiday in Asia, and he acesses the website from Asia. I'm currently located in Switzerland.

1 - Wrong:
[image: Example 1 wrong]

1 - Right:
[image: Example 1 right]

2 - Wrong:
[image: Example 2 wrong]

2 - Right:
[image: Example 2 right]

What I already found out by observing this, is that the same letters always transform to the same wrong letters.

e.g: When "p" gets displayed wrong, it gets displayed as a "q" (same story with "s" and "t" and also "c" and "d"). But it does not always get displayed wrong.
Also the wrong letters seem to be displayed in a different font.

Comment: Try the [`translate`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_translate.asp) attribute

Comment: @CarlJan How would this help me? The user has to have the possibility to translate the text